# FFMPEG Error while opening decoder for input stream

Tags: ffmpeg

While this command his been working for a couple of months, I suddenly began running into the following error when encoding video via my php application.  Testing the encoding parameters on the command line yielded the same results, while the verion of ffmpeg on my local machine has no problem reading the input

Command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i clip_20121022150813.mp4 -acodec libfaac -ab 44100 encoded.mp4
```

And the output (error on last line):

```
ffmpeg version N-45871-g34ccb94 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 22 2012 22:20:53 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      51. 77.100 / 51. 77.100
  libavcodec     54. 68.100 / 54. 68.100
  libavformat    54. 34.100 / 54. 34.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 20.104 /  3. 20.104
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
  libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_20121022150813.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2012-10-22 22:08:02
  Duration: 00:00:03.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3259 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x640, 2593 kb/s, 18.73 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-22 22:08:02
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-22 22:08:02
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
File 'encoded.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x104fa4e0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x104fa4e0] 264 - core 128 r2216 198a7ea - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'encoded.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x640, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-22 22:08:02
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 44 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-22 22:08:02
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libfaac)
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0
```

I have uninstalled ffmpeg, recompiled from source, also recompiled x264 and a host of other libraries, but this error persists.  Is there anyway I can find out more about what exactly is failing?

Comment: First let me congratulate you on using a recent ffmpeg, and for using a simple and sane configuration. Are you saying that the input is successfully decoded by an older ffmpeg? Can you provide the input so I can attempt to duplicate this issue? Also, check the md5sum on the input on both machines to make sure that they are the same.